# Javascript IF statement not recognising integer other than 0 in a function

Tags: javascript

I have an IF function in a FOR loop that is not recognising any integer values other than 0.

The code is below, and the IF function with the problem is:
 if (x==0) {curr_year = curr_year;}

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var r_array = [
'Row 1',
'Row 2',
'Row 3'
];

var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var array_months = months.concat(months);

var x = parseInt(0);
var text_r = "";
var row = "";
var report = "";
var d = new Date();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);         // 2017 = 17
var prior_year = (d.getFullYear()-1).toString().substr(2,2);
var curr_month = d.getMonth();                                  // Jan = 0

for (var i_row = 0; i_row < r_array.length; i_row++) { 

    report = r_array[i_row]
    text_r += ("<tr><th>" + report + "</th>"+ this_row(report) +"</tr>");
    row = "";
}

function this_row(report) {
    x = 0;
    for (i_col = curr_month; i_col < curr_month + 13; i_col++) {    
        if (x==0) {
            curr_year = curr_year;
            }
        else {
            curr_year = prior_year;
            }

        row += "<td><a href = '"+ curr_year +"' target='blank'>" + array_months[i_col] + "-"+ curr_year +"</a></td>";
        x++;
    }
    curr_year = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);
    return row;
}

</script>
```

With x = 0 the year in the first column shows as '17' as expected
However, when x is changed to 1, the year in the second column does not show as '17'

I have replicated the FOR loop in a second script with the same variables, but outside of a function, and it works OK.  Therefore, I'm wondering whether the problem is related to running the FOR loop within a function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you want row to be at end of the call to this_row()?

Comment: What is the output you are getting and what were you expecting?

Comment: With the code as shown above (x = 0) the year in the first column shows as '17' as expected.   However, when the if function is changed to (x = 1)  I expect the year in the SECOND column to show as '17' but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the result that you want by calculating the curr_year and prior_year ever time the loop execute so you don't loose the value of curr_year after the first iteration of the forLoop.

Another change that I made in order to get what you want is to change the if statement depending on what column you need to get the value so the code would be something like this:

```
function this_row(report) {
x = 0;
for (i_col = curr_month; i_col < curr_month + 13; i_col++) {
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);         // 2017 = 17
    var prior_year = (d.getFullYear()-1).toString().substr(2,2);
    if (x==2) {
        curr_year = curr_year;
        }
    else {
        curr_year = prior_year;
        }

    row += "<td><a href = '"+ curr_year +"' target='blank'>" + array_months[i_col] + "-"+ curr_year +"</a></td>";
    x++;
}
curr_year = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);
return row;
```

}

So for example here I used `if(x==2)` to get the third column with the value '17' if you want the second just change it for `if(x==1)`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Fantastic - this solved the problem!  Thank you EAragon, and to everbody else who looked into this issue,

Answer (score 0):

When your function is called, the scope of `x` it referred is not the same `x` you defined. Change the function to use a local variable `x`

```
function this_row(report) {
    var x = 0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response Anthony.  However, I made the change you suggested and unfortunately it had no effect.

Comment: It has no effect because you are incrementing x by one hence it will fall in the else clause, using prior year.

Comment: But say for example I change to IF (x>1) I would expect all columns from 2 onwards to have the curr_year .... but it still returns prior year

Comment: @OneBigEgg, can you do a `console.log(_col, curr_month)` to see what you get?